# Encrypting a 4 digit password/pincode - easy to crack?

Tags: database, security, encryption, mobile, twilio

I am currently working on a service which requires users to pick a 4-digit password/pin, because it is a mobile service. I am encrypting those passwords with either 256 or 2048bit encryption and it will be hashed. The account is blocked after 4 wrong entries, and can only be entered by mobile phone. Would it be hard to crack those PINs? I am asking this because sensitive information is being stored. The database is connected to a web application, the application is loaded to the phone using twilio. The thing I am most scared for is that the database is being hacked via the web. What would be a good way to keep sensitive data secure?

Comment: When you say "can only be entered by mobile phone", what do you mean?  Do you know that the login attempt is coming from a device controlled by the account owner as verified by some independent channel?  Or is the message coming from a channel that can receive messages from a large number of mobile phones?

Comment: Are you encrypting or hashing?  They're two different things, and to be used for different occasions.  
4 digit pin generates a keyspace of only 10000, so which even with 4 wrong attempts, it's not impossible to get lucky.  
Could you explain more about where the db is, and whether it's the phone or the central server doing the authentication?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Twilio detects if someone is calling in by phone and detects the number. If the number is in the database the user can proceed to enter his PIN. But if a hacker wants to break in, that wouldn't be the best way, he would just try to get hold of my database. That's what scares me the most.                                        Does anyone know what the average cost is of securing the database sufficiently? From reading this I noticed that doing this by myself probably wont be the way to go. In what way would a SSL certificate help?

Answer (score 6):

If someone gets hold of the database, you would be pretty much screwed:

If you just encrypt the 4-digit passwords, an attacker can just build a table of the 10000 possible encrypted strings and can trivially decrypt the PINs.

If you use salt strings (and encrypt not PIN, but PIN+salt and store crypted(PIN+salt) alongside with salt), people have to make a per-password effort, but there are still only 10000 possibilities for each password (which is not very much).

Which means, yes, by all means you should keep the database off the web. (If the web application is only ever accessed through twilio, you can reject connections from any other IP range).

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using twilio, just make sure that twilo only talks to your web service using a secure protocol and reject any requests that you aren't sure are coming from a trusted source (that is, twilo). No real need for a pin at all.

This is a huge webpage on how to setup ssl between your web server and twilo. It even has a php example.
http://www.twilio.com/docs/security

Comment: Thanks alot! Reading through that page now. The PIN, however, is needed in case of the phone being stolen. But what happens with the connection from the web application from and to the database? Can that be intercepted?

Comment: Databases should never be exposed directly to the internet. There should always be an application layer that deals with requests from the internet and decides whether to respond or not. SSL should make interception of traffic between twilio and your web app virtually pointless. Theoretically no form of encryption is impenetrable, all you can do is make the time or cost involved in breaking the encryption more effort than it's worth.

Comment: Use client side authentication with SSL/TSL to protect against main-in-the-middle attacks.

Answer (score 2):

If you use PKCS#1 1.5 or 2.0 RSA encryption ([view the standards](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2125)) you will also encrypt a random padding. This means that in transit, the PIN's cannot be compared, as long as the padding is kept secret and is truly random (this is not a salt which should be made public).

As for the database, it would be a good idea to move it out of the normal operations as much as possible. Create a simple service that just checks the PIN after decryption, make sure you don't have buffer overruns etc. on that, and if possible, use a different machine and access rights than the production server. Really test this part well, as the interface is small, it should not be difficult.

If you and the phones are up to it, you might want to try ECC, but that's not for the meek. RSA encrypt normally uses a small public exponent (0x010001 is highly recommended) so it is faster than ECC for the phone. On the server (and during key creation) ECC is much faster. I would not recommend symmetric cryptography (AES/3DES) for this.

Oh, and include the public encryption key in the application (for implicit trust), don't send it over from the server. Keep the private key secret and inaccessible for anything other than the already mentioned service.

Answer (score 1):

The interface you describe sounds secure to me. It's secure enough for ATMs!

Are the encrypted PINs easy to crack? Yes, there's only 10000 possible combinations and a [rainbow table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) can be generated of all the possible encrypted values unless you [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29). However that would require access to the encrypted PINs which means the attacker already has a copy of your database.

So really you need to ensure your database server is secure. There's a lot of variables that could make it insecure so it's a big question. Instead you could rely on third-party solutions like [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) or [others](http://www.readwriteweb.com/cloud/2011/01/7-cloud-based-database-service.php) and concentrate on coding instead of security. Let them do the hard work!

Comment: The interface is not well explaind enough. How are remote connections validated as "entered by a mobile phone" What protection is given to the 4-digit number in transit? How is the user authenticating the server to protect against man-in-the middle attacks? What crypto variables are used to encrypt the 4-digit number? How are user's disuaded from sharing their 4-digit number with other people?

Answer (score 0):

You should use good quality password salting technique to prevent against hacking passwords. Check the wikipedia article to know more about salting. [Salt Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29)